# Pandas - Comparing None values

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this snippet:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[None]])
b = pd.DataFrame([[None]])
```

Now, I want to validate both of them contains the exact same values:

```
int((a == b).sum())  # should be 1
```

but it's not 1. Instead, it returns 0. This behavior is giving me troubles especially in `assert_frame_equal` where it is reporting `None` is not `None` even though they are:

```
a.iloc[0,0] == b.iloc[0,0]  # True
```

Why is that and how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you trying compulsorily count, or is True/False enough?

Comment: Ultimately I would like `assert_frame_equal` to work as expected, ie, None is indeed equal to None.

Comment: By the by, I think this is almost certainly a bug, these Nones are internally interpreted as NaNs somehow, leading to this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas is special casing `None` so as to be interpreted as `NaN` (since `NaN != NaN`, and `pd.isnull` treats both consistently... this may be one explanation).

Not a solution, but a workaround – `np.array_equal` works, if they're `None` and not `NaN`;

```
>>> np.array_equal(a, b)
True
```

If you want the count and not a bool result, use `np.equal`;

```
>>> np.equal(a, b).sum().item()
1
```

Comment: Is there a way to make Pandas not treat None's as NaN's?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Not that I'm aware, but you can do silly things like `a.fillna(0) == b.fillna(0)`, or `(a.isnull() & b.isnull()).sum()` and so on, depending on your actual use case.

Comment: The problem is that I would like to use `assert_frame_equal` to deal with the whole floating point madness. `np.array_equal` returns `False` because of some precision issues but I don't really care about those in my unit test.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 if Alexander's answer doesn't do it for you, then try `np.allclose`: `np.allclose(a.astype(float), b.astype(float), equal_nan=True)`

Comment: To complicate things, the dataframes actually contain some non-numeric types :) I might have to replace None's with a constant then.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I don't think this is a bug. "The choice of using NaN internally to denote missing data was largely for simplicity and performance reasons." https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

Comment: @Alexander Sure, that was speculation from my side anyway.